# jquery show hide div step by step

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

I know that could be noob question...

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/115/) but my problem is that animation works same time...
I mean when DIV1 is opened and you're opening DIV2 it works same time. Is there a chance to make it work step by step. When DIV1 is opened and you're clicking DIV2 to open, it should first close DIV1 and than open DIV2.

```
    $('.navLink').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if(!targetDiv.is(':visible')){
        $('.page').slideUp();
        targetDiv.slideDown();
    }else{
        $('.page').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. It *is* closing div1 before opening `div2`, that's what `$('.page').slideUp();` does.

Comment: i might not described it well... i'll try once again! So DIV1 is open, i'm clicking DIV2 to open and closing DIV1 and opening DIV slid wors same time. Is there a chance to close (hide) DIV1 and only after open (show) DIV2?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding delay like this:

```
$('.page').slideUp().delay(1000);
```

Here is JSFiddle:
     http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/118/

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `setTimeout`

```
$('.navLink').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));
    if(!targetDiv.is(':visible')){
        $('.page').slideUp();
        setTimeout(function(){targetDiv.slideDown()}, 500); //edited this line only

    }else{
        $('.page').slideUp();
    }
});
```

#### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fKGc5/116/)

Comment: Excatly what i need! Cheers!

Comment: I wouldn't use `setTimeout()` here, mainly because jQuery has delay methods.

Comment: @Shahar Noted...thanks for pointing out the distinction. Aleksandr, other answer below is using delay().  You can adjust the time there to meet your needs.

Comment: no need to specify any timeout's.  jQuery has a complete function property that can be specified that will be called when the animation is done and then trigger the next animation.  The timeout will break if a different animation time is specified for the animation.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a complete callback on the slideUp and then trigger the slideDown

```
$('.page').slideUp({
    complete: function() {
         targetDiv.slideDown();
    }
});
```